# Implementing LDAP over TLS

Tags: java, ssl

I am using the following piece of code in my code for enabling tls over ldap.

```
import javax.naming.ldap.*;

 // Open an LDAP association
 LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext();

 // Perform a StartTLS extended operation
 StartTlsResponse tls =
     (StartTlsResponse) ctx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());

 // Open a TLS connection (over the existing LDAP association) and get details
 // of the negotiated TLS session: cipher suite, peer certificate, ...
 SSLSession session = tls.negotiate();

 // ... use ctx to perform protected LDAP operations

 // Close the TLS connection (revert back to the underlying LDAP association)
 tls.close();

 // ... use ctx to perform unprotected LDAP operations

 // Close the LDAP association
 ctx.close;
```

My question is since the StartTLSResponse class is abstract class and its methods like negotiate and close are abstract. Do i need to implement this methods or simply using the above code will work.

Since i got the code from
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/StartTlsResponse.html#close%28%29

Comment: You have it back to front. You're taking about implementing LDAP over TLS. The other way round doesn't make sense.

Comment: apologies, was in hurry thats why did that mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since the StartTLSResponse class is abstract class and its methods like negotiate and close are abstract. Do i need to implement this methods

No. You get a concrete instance of the class that already does that.

> or simply using the above code will work.

The code works. I tried it yesterday.